# Polymer: building nested paper-tabs and core-pages

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am trying to create nested `paper-tabs` and `core-pages`. My problem is that after **Tab 2** is selected, **Page Content 11** or **Page Content 12** is left over. How do I hide the unselected "page content", enclosed by `div` in my case?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="my-page.html">
    <style>
        html,body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-size:62.5%;
        }
        core-header-panel {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
            font-size:3em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body unresolved>
    <core-header-panel>
        <my-page id="p"></my-page>
    </core-header-panel>
    <script>
        data=[
            {
                TabCaption:"Tab 1"
                ,children:[
                    {
                        TabCaption:"Tab 11"
                        ,PageContent:"Page Content 11"
                        ,children:null
                    }
                    ,{
                        TabCaption:"Tab 12"
                        ,PageContent:"Page Content 12"
                        ,children:null
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,{
                TabCaption:"Tab 2"
                ,PageContent:"Page Content 2"
                ,children:null
            }
        ];
        document.querySelector("#p").pages=data;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my-page.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
<polymer-element name="my-page" attributes="pages">
    <template repeat if="{{pages}}">
        <style>
            paper-tabs {
                margin: 0;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #F00;
                background-color: #00BCD4;
            }
            core-selected {
                background-color: #00FF00;
            }
            paper-tab {
                font-size:1.6em;
            }
        </style>
        <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" flex self-end layout>
            <template repeat="{{p in pages}}">
                <paper-tab>{{p.TabCaption}}</paper-tab>
            </template>
        </paper-tabs>
        <core-pages selected="{{selected}}">
            <template repeat="{{p in pages}}">
                <div one flex vertical layout>
                    <template if="{{p.PageContent}}">
                        {{p.PageContent}}
                    </template>
                    <template if="{{p.children}}">
                        <my-page pages="{{p.children}}"></my-page>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </core-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            selected:0
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thank you in advance for the enlightenment!

[image: TAB 1 - TAB 11]

[image: Circled content should be hidden.]

**Edit:**
@JoppeSchwartz:
Thank you for your kind help! I learn a lot from it.

Iceweasel v.35 behaves the same as those screen shots in my original post. Chromium v.40 renders incorrect effects.

[image: Chromium - clicking on "TAB 1"]
[image: Chromium - clicking on "TAB 2"]
[image: Iceweasel - clicking on "TAB 1"]
[image: Iceweasel - clicking on "TAB 2"]

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the elements in the browser debugger, I find that the div enclosing the PageContent is being rendered with zero height. To resolve this, I used the following steps:

1. In `index.html`:

   - Add the `fullbleed` attribute to the `<body>` element, per [the Polymer layout docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#full-bleed-ltbody). This tells the body to take up all available space in the viewport.

     ```
     <body unresolved fullbleed>
     ```
   - Add the `vertical layout` and `flex` attributes to the code in the body so that they take up available vertical space:

     ```
     <core-header-panel vertical layout>
         <my-page flex id="p"></my-page>
     </core-header-panel>
     ```
2. In `my-page.html`:

   - Add the `vertical layout` attributes to the `<my page>` component and the `flex` attribute to the ` element so that it takes up :

     ```
         <polymer-element name="my-page" attributes="pages" vertical layout>
         . . . 
         <core-pages selected="{{selected}}" flex>
     ```
   - At this point, the `<paper-tabs>` will be pushed to the right side of the page. This is not what you want, I gather, so remove the `self-end` attribute:

     ```
         <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" layout>
     ```
   - Finally, although this is not strictly necessary, I noticed that the `core-selected` selector in your style section should read `.core-selected` if you want to select the CSS class of that name.

For completeness, here are the edited versions of your code:

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="my-page.html">
    <style>
        html,body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-size:62.5%;
        }
        core-header-panel {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
            font-size:3em;
                    }
    </style>
</head>
<body unresolved fullbleed>
    <core-header-panel vertical layout>
        <my-page flex id="p"></my-page>
    </core-header-panel>
    <script>
        data=[
            {
                TabCaption:"Tab 1"
                ,children:[
                    {
                        TabCaption:"Tab 11"
                        ,PageContent:"Page Content 11"
                        ,children:null
                    }
                    ,{
                        TabCaption:"Tab 12"
                        ,PageContent:"Page Content 12"
                        ,children:null
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,{
                TabCaption:"Tab 2"
                ,PageContent:"Page Content 2"
                ,children:null
            }
        ];
        document.querySelector("#p").pages=data;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### my-page.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
<polymer-element name="my-page" attributes="pages" vertical layout>
    <template repeat if="{{pages}}">
        <style>
            paper-tabs {
                margin: 0;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: #F00;
                background-color: #00BCD4;
                            }

            .core-selected {
                            background-color: #00FF00;
            }
            paper-tab {
                font-size:1.6em;
                            }
        </style>
        <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" layout>
            <template repeat="{{p in pages}}">
                <paper-tab>{{p.TabCaption}}</paper-tab>
            </template>
        </paper-tabs>
        <core-pages selected="{{selected}}" flex>
            <template repeat="{{p in pages}}">
                <div one flex vertical layout>
                    <template if="{{p.PageContent}}">
                        {{p.PageContent}}
                    </template>
                    <template if="{{p.children}}">
                        <my-page pages="{{p.children}}"></my-page>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </template>
        </core-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            selected:0
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```